# Need help to understand a project in new domain

Tags: java

I need to work on s&op domain. As I am very new to this domain, and there was no documentation provided for the project. How can I proceed further to understand the domain and project. That project was built on very older technologies like ejb 2.x javascript, normal jsp pages. What can I do to get the most out of the project. I asked help from senior persons, they also don't know completely about the project. Please suggest me what to do? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the S&OP domain, I suppose that you could start by reading [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sales_and_operations_planning) ... *and the pages that it links to*.

To understand the code base, you are just going to have to read the code and reverse engineer the design.  I'd recommend using a good IDE to help you navigate the code.  Also, a tool or IDE plugin that can generate UML-style class diagrams for the code would be helpful.

I would strongly recommend creating some architecture documentation to document what you figure out  ... so that the next guy who has to deal with the code-base is better off than you were when you started.  Make sure that management gives you time to do that task.  (If they didn't, I'd quietly start looking for another job ...)

I'd also recommend that you figure out how much test code there is in the code-base, and how to run the tests.  If the existing test code isn't adequate, the first thing you need to do before making changes is to write code to test the major system functions from the outside ...

Finally, make sure that you set up a test system that is as close as possible to the production system.  Ideally get a bunch of real users who know how the current system is supposed to work to test out any changes that you make ... on the test system of course.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. Your suggestions are really wonderful